# Specifying Correlation strength prior to plotting using corrr

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame of correlations where I'm trying to only sow the correlations above 10%
I want to then plot this using the `corrr` package

I take the correlation of my data set, then filter to where the absolute value is >.1 but it fails on the network plot segment

> Error in UseMethod("network_plot") : 
>     no applicable method for 'network_plot' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

# Create the Dataframe
mydf <- data.frame(a=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   b=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   c=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   d=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   e=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   f=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE))


test <- mydf %>% 
  correlate(method = "spearman") %>% 
  gather("n", "corr", 2:7, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(abs(corr) > 0.1) %>% 
  spread(rowname,corr) %>%
  network_plot(legend = TRUE)
```

I see in the [documentation](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr) for the package that you can specify the correlations you wish to visualize, however that seems to still print the labels even if i have asked for them not to be included which is why I went down the gather/spread route

```
  network_plot(min_cor = .2, legend = TRUE)
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: You lost the `cor_df` class somewhere between the `correlate` call and `network_plot`. So do `test = mydf %>% ... %>% spread(rowname, corr)`, then `class(test) = c("cor_df", class(test))`, then do `network_plot(test, legend = TRUE)`.

Comment: You should also be able to just force calling `network_plot.cor_df`: `test = mydf %>% ... %>% corrr:::network_plot.cor_df(legend = TRUE)`

Comment: Also consider filing this as an [issue](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr/issues) on the `corrr` GitHub page since there should be a `network_plot.default` method, which it appears there isn't.

Comment: Also, I think you need `spread(n, corr)` rather than `spread(rowname, corr)` for `network_plot` to work properly.

Comment: Hi @epi, i changed the spread but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Hi @MichaelChirico I wasn't able to force the plot in the example. Would you be able to provide a more detailed answer. I will stick it on the GitHub issues board in the meantime

Comment: I don't really know the package and am too lazy to install it (which is why I left this as a comment), sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for alerting me to this issue via email (which I'll reply separately to when I have some more time). I'll put down a quick solution now.

This is an interesting problem. From what I can gather, you want to completely exclude any variables that don't correlate above an absolute magnitude with any other.

As you noted, specifying `min_cor` will stop the paths from being plotted, but not the variables themselves.

I'll probably add an issue to the GitHub page and try to address it in the future. For now, here's a work-around with some help from the purrr package.

```
library(corrr)
library(purrr)

mydf <- data.frame(a=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   b=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   c=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   d=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   e=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE),
                   f=sample(rnorm(n = 100,sd = 15),replace=TRUE))

# Create the correlation data frame
rdf <- mydf %>% correlate(method = "spearman")

# Identify which variables to keep
to_keep <- map_lgl(rdf, ~ !is.numeric(.) || any(abs(.) > .1))
to_keep <- names(to_keep)[!is.na(to_keep)]

# Create the network plot
rdf %>%
  focus_(.dots = to_keep, mirror = TRUE) %>% 
  network_plot(legend = TRUE, min_cor = .1)
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to install the latest development version of corrr via `devtools::install_github("drsimonj/corrr")`

Comment: Hi @Simon Jackson. Thank you for responding. When i run this code it plots the rownames a-f on the chart but it doesn't seem to plot the the correlations themselves - the lines between the labels signifying a relationship

Comment: @JohnSmith I think it could be one of two things. (1) Given the correlations are close to zero (.1), they're probably barely visible anyway. (2) Sometimes you need to zoom (i.e., click the zoom button on the plotting panel if using RStudio) for the paths to show.

Comment: Hi @Simon Jackson. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. This is exactly what i was trying to accomplish. You are right. It seems the correlations were too low to be visible in the chart. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @JohnSmith :)
For anyone else following this, we've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr/issues/30) with what seems to be a promising solution to this and similar problems.